# Forum written in Python?

Tags: django

I am looking to make an interactive forum in Python/Django. I googled up things, looked up on your site ( there is a question where a person wants to implement a Digg like system ) but nothing definite has come up for what I want an answer to.

Is it possible to write a basic interactive forum in Python which allows say login system for one with defined roles for users, different categories say Literature and Science for now. Upload and download feature in each of the category. Also, I would like to have some good GUI.

So, is it possible? ( my search uptil now says it is ) but it would then require for me to go through PHP or something else.

What I really want to know is that is it possible to do it entirely in Django/Python ( includes everything for managing database and stuff )? If not, how much PHP and other stuff do I need?

And how much work am I looking at it in Python/Django? ( Like is it a good thing to have over PHP and/or any other system already in place)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Python is a general purpose programming language, thus, it is completely capable of creating just about any kind of interactive forum you can imagine. You would not have to use any PHP... this could be done completely in Python. There are [many forums](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ForumAppsComparison) already created in Django.

Comment: Thanks. Also, does Python/Django gives any added advantage to me than using/writing a PHP based system for the same purpose?

Comment: @Sylar PHP is notoriously insecure in general, other than that not really.